# no Sql data returned even though it exists

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my sqlquery :

```
SELECT *
FROM work_orders
WHERE LineKey = 'ABC' 
AND StateKey  = 'Approved' 
AND orderKey = 'Released' 
AND WOID NOT IN (
    SELECT WOID 
    FROM serialized_assembly
    GROUP BY (WOID)
    HAVING COUNT(WOID) > 9
    )   
LIMIT 1
```

Which does not return any data even though there's an WOID 1234 that passes all these conditions.

When I break this query into two parts:
part1)

```
SELECT *
FROM work_orders
WHERE LineKey = 'ABC' AND StateKey  = 'Approved' AND orderKey = 'Released'
```

I can see WOID 1234 in my results

part2)

```
SELECT WOID 
FROM serialized_assembly
GROUP BY (WOID)
HAVING COUNT(WOID) > 9
```

I can see that WOID 1234 is not a part of that group in the results

However, when I combine those two, I get nothing. Is there anything wrong with the sql query ?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: Conflicting TAGS removed, please add back the one for the database you are actually using

Comment: `NOT IN (null)` issue?

Comment: *Is there anything wrong with the sql query* - technically no, but unexpected results can occur if your data allows for nulls - use *not exists* instead.

Comment: @jarlh I'm using MYSQL

Comment: perhaps! how would I fix that? @jarlh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NOT IN (null)` is probably the problem here, because that will never be TRUE.

You can use `NOT EXISTS` instead, or compare the count:

```
SELECT *
FROM work_orders
WHERE LineKey = 'ABC' 
AND StateKey  = 'Approved' 
AND orderKey = 'Released' 
AND (SELECT COUNT(WOID)
     FROM serialized_assembly
     WHERE work_orders.WOID = serialized_assembly.WOID) <= 9
LIMIT 1
```